# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am getting an error .
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (id)' at line 1**
 Not sure why . Can anyone help ?
Below are entities. Order can have many products. Products can be associated to many orders and a restaurant has one to one relationship with product

```
    @Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "order_product", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();

    }


    @Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", referencedColumnName = "id",  insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Restaurant restaurant;
    private int restaurant_id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private float price;
    private float discount;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Order> orders = new HashSet<>();
    }



 @Entity
public class Restaurant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "restaurant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Product> menu;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Order is having multiple product that is okay and correct also. But Logically it is not right to associate Orders with Products. So I think if just remove following line from Product entity it will solve your problem.

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "order_product", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="order_id", referencedColumnName = "order_id"))
private Set<Order> order;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still getting the error . I have added the complete error in my question, may be that can help you to identify the issue better

Comment: Also when i remove order set from product, I am getting error "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement",' On making a post call to order with body , {
 "product":[{
  "name":"test",
  "restaurant_id" : "1",
  "description":"test"
 }]
}